# An interruptible version of nav stack?

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This question is related to my [earlier](http://answers.ros.org/question/12085/preventing-move-base-from-executing-a-queued-up-goal/) one on the nav stack.

Suppose I'm sending `move_base` a goal; I want to be able to interrupt `move_base`  during its plan execution. Afaik, the current nav stack doesn't allow this.

> Is it better to design an "interruptible" nav stack, or are there other alternatives?

As an example of alternative: I could get a global plan from the `~make_plan` , and directly use `cmd_vel` to navigate between waypoints. These commands can be turned off when an interrupt flag is set.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/136116/an-interruptible-version-of-nav-stack?/) by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 365 on 2014-03-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-03-05**:
Do you just want to interrupt the nav stack (i.e. get it to pause) or would stopping the action and then restarting it work?

**Comment by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) on 2014-03-05**:
Stopping the action for good, and restarting it later if needed, is OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[move_base](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base) exposes two APIs: a simple topic for recieving goals ( `move_base_simple/goal` ) and an actionlib server ( `move_base/goal`, `move_base/cancel`, etc).

The actionlib server supports queuing and canceling goals, so it does in fact support canceling a goal while it is in progress.

[This tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals) describes how to set up an actionlib client to send goals to the navigation stack, and the [actionlib API documentation](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/actionlib/html/classactionlib_1_1SimpleActionClient.html) documents the various cancel functions that are available.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2